# Converting Spamassassin rules to rspamd

Tags: spam-prevention, spamassassin

I set up a new mail server using rspamd. I have sets of rules from spamassasin.

I would like to import/convert them to rspamd.
What I did:

- Created file with rules on `/etc/rspamd/custom/spamassasin.map`
- Added config in `local.d/spamassassin.conf`:

  `ruleset = "/etc/rspamd/custom/spamassasin.map";`
- Restarted rspamd

In logs there are errors:

```
#1(main) <83zuwt>; lua; spamassassin.lua:871: unknown function Subject:raw=~/=\?(UTF|utf)-8\?B\?4(p|q)/
#1(main) <83zuwt>; lua; spamassassin.lua:871: unknown function From=~/Administrator/
#1(main) <83zuwt>; lua; spamassassin.lua:871: unknown function To=~/Recipients /
#1(main) <83zuwt>; lua; spamassassin.lua:871: unknown function Subject=~/(?: darmo| gratis|bez op.{1,8}at)/
#1(main) <83zuwt>; lua; spamassassin.lua:871: unknown function Subject=~/\-\d+\%/
```

Rules are fetched from: https://github.com/zabojcaspamu/spamassassin_rules/blob/master/local.cf.reguly.ZABOJCASPAMU
and looks lik:

```
header   ZABOJCASPAMU_SUBJECT_KREDYT  Subject=~/(?:(K|k)redyt| po.{1,8}yczka)/
describe ZABOJCASPAMU_SUBJECT_KREDYT  W temacie slowo kredyt lub pozyczka
score    ZABOJCASPAMU_SUBJECT_KREDYT  0.8
```

Question is how to make it work or how to write/convert this rules to rspamd format. I didn't find a similar way as in Spamassassin on rspamd documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I've seen something similar in the past - does this error disappear if you add spaces around `=~` operator in SA rules? If yes, then could you please open an issue in Rspamd bug tracker: https://github.com/vstakhov/rspamd/issues ?

Comment: Yes. After adding space around `=~` everything works well. I mean no errors :) Thanks!